# Is the Nelson-Laplacian $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}$ on a Lie group $G$ an elliptic differential operator?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-operators

Let $G$ be a Lie group of dimension $n\in \mathbb N$ and let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be a basis of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ act by left-invariant vectorfields on smooth functions on $G$. Is it true that the left-invariant differential operator given by the element
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2} 
$$
in the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is an elliptic differential operator ? If so how can one prove this?

Im currently working with the book Representation theory of semisimple groups by Anthony W. Knapp and im currently stuck in the proof of Theorem 8.7 where he proves that all matrix coefficients $g \mapsto \langle \pi(g)v,w\rangle$ are real analytic functions whenever $(\pi,V)$ is an admissible representation of G on a Hilbertspace V and $v$ is a K-finite vector in $V$ and $w \in V$. Here G is assumed to be connected linear reductive. He shows that a certain elliptic differential operator $D$ annihilates the matrix coefficient and since it is elliptic and has real analytic coefficients the matrix coefficient has to be analytic aswell. If I would know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}$ is elliptic I could deduce that $D$ is elliptic as well.

Knapp says that one can see that it is elliptic if one looks at $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}$
 in canonical coordinates of the first kind given by the exponential map relative to the basis $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ . I tried this but I failed. I would really appreciate the help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely confident that I remember the context of such a discussion in Knapp's books, but...

First, the literal expression $\sum_i X_i^2$ for an arbitrary basis of the Lie algebra is not well-defined, by far. Not even close.

Second, a well-defined thing is $\sum_i X_i\cdot X_i^*$, where $X_i^*$ are the dual basis vectors via the Killing form... for a semi-simple Lie algebra. This gives the Casimir operator, whose basis-independence can be verified by silly calculations (as are popular), or by coordinate-free characterizations.

Even then, the Casimir element is not at all elliptic unless the Lie group is compact. But, on functions on $G$ with restricted right $K$-type, it *is* elliptic, etc.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the very quick answer. Can you elaborate on why the $\sum_{i}X_{i}^{2}$ is not well defined?  If we let $\tilde{X}(f)(g):=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(g\exp(tX))$ we get a map from $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{R}}$ to the left invariant differentialoperators which extends to the universal enveloping algebra of $G$. This is an algebra isomorphism between the universal enveloping algebra of $G$ and the  algebra of left invariant differential operators on G. That's how I interpreted $\sum_{i}X_{i}^{2}$ but maybe I just misunderstand something here.

Comment: Well, for a choice of basis that operator is well-defined, but it is very much dependent upon choice of basis, in your description of it. Even for compact Lie groups, your expression is very much basis-dependent, since it does not take into account the geometry/inner-products (Killing-form) among the $X_i$. And then for non-compact but semi-simple cases the signature of the invariant quadratic form requires some sign adjustments, at the very least...

Comment: Ok, so in Knapp's book he looks at a Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{p} \oplus \mathfrak{t}$ and he chooses orthonormal bases $(X_{i})_{i}$ of $\mathfrak{t}$  and $(Y_{j})_{j}$ of $\mathfrak{p}$ and then he looks at the Operator $\sum_{i}X_{i}  + \sum_{j}Y_{j}$ as defined above. Maybe this additional structure makes it work.

Comment: Why does it matter if it depends upon a basis? The isomorphism I mentioned above gives us a well defined left invariant differential operator on $G$. Isn't this enough to ask whether this specific differential operator is elliptic or not?

Comment: I believe that the answer to the original question is "yes".   The differential operator $\sum_i X_i^2$ depends on the choice of basis, but I believe for any choice of basis it's elliptic.  What is your favorite characterization of elliptic differential operators?  If you use a definition involving the principal symbol, I think the ellipticity is clear.